# Linux giving severe problems with Windows dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, grub2, windows, mint

Can someone help me out with this issue? My laptop has been giving me problems since quite a while now. I had a single Ubuntu 18.04 running that was lagging my system so much that I had to clean install it again. However, it again started giving problems such as

```
ACPI error, 
blk_update_request: I/O error,
Failed to start Network Time Synchronization, etc.
```

All of these issues really bugged me off because it was tiresome to run a manual fsck everytime I wanted to boot up the system, so I migrated to Linux mint. The first time the installation failed, and I ran a boot repair. The pastebin link can found [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/TyqCdGqMMq/).

Can someone look into it and let me know what exactly to do in this case?

Comment: Maybe your hardrive is faulty. Run a live ubuntu and then disks to check the drive status.

Answer (score 1):

I see one simple solution to clean up the disk and do it all over again. In order like:

1. Create 1 (or 2, with "reserved") partitions for Windows, and lave free space
2. Install Windows
3. Boot Linux, create partitions, install it
4. Run os-prober to create grub entry for other system

Enjoy.